Obtener path mediante FSO.GetAbsolutePathName mostrando el resultado con barra diagonal "/"
Tengo el siguiente código en visual basic script que detecta el path y reemplaza una palabra por el path
Al ejecutarse el código la palabra sera reemplazada por el path. Quedando de la siguiente manera
C:\proyectos. Lo que deseo es que el resultado me salga con la barra diagonal "/". Debería quedar así: C:/proyectos. No he logrado encontrar la función exacta para lograr lo que deseo, no se si exista, o si se debe añadir o modificar algo en el código.
Como podría hacer para lograrlo ?
OldTextFile = ".\Archivo.txt" 
NewTextFile = ".\Archivo-nuevo.txt" 
ReplaceFrom = "Palabra1" 
ReplaceTo = FSO.GetAbsolutePathName(".") 

FSO.CreateTextFile(NewTextFile, 2). _ 
Write(Replace(FSO.OpenTextFile(OldTextFile, 1).ReadAll(), _ 
ReplaceFrom, ReplaceTo, 1, -1, vbTextCompare))````






